# How to get the value on a specific row by searching?

Tags: vb.net, gridview

How to get the value on a specific row by searching?

i.e., I have a gridview:

```
A   B   C 
---------
1   2   3 
2   3   4 
3   4   5
```

Then, I want to get the "**3**" value from column '**A**'. But I do not know the exactly row number because it can be randomly show. Fyi, in order to get the "3" value, you have to compare it to a variable. So, if the variable contains '2', then I should find the '2' value on the gridview.

How can I do that? Thank you very much..

Comment: That depends on your GridView. Is `AutoGenerateColumns=true`, are you using TemplateFields or BoundFields, is paging enabled, is sorting enabled ...? Normally you would search the datasource instead of the GridView. What are you actually tring to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check by looping the rows of gridview, see the below code

```
    Dim num As Integer = 2
    For Each DRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If (DRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString = num.ToString) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Matched")
        End If
    Next
```

Note : The above code is a sample written on datagridview, you change the code to a gridview and check.

Comment: I assume that OP means the _ASP.NET_ [`GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w7ya1ts%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I gave him some idea about to get the value from a grid, so i mentioned in the Note also.

Comment: @SaiKalyanAkshinthala & TimSchmelter: Thanks, I figured it out :)